# Ajax variable to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

Hey :) How do i get the variable test, sending the file path string and not echo "$test". I want to run a php function where it sees the file path and runds accordingly.

Heres what i have thus far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".link-text").click(function(){
            var $contentPanelId = jQuery(this).attr("id");
            var $test= ("Images/Pictures/materials/" + $contentPanelId + "/");

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',

                url: 'php_functions.php?name=$test',

                success: function(path) 
                {
                     $( '#somthing' ).append( path );
                }
            }); 
   });
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `'php_functions.php?name=' + $test` or `data : { name: $test }`

Comment: nitpick: there's no such thing as an "ajax variable". you have a javascript variable, whose value you want to transfer via an ajax call, which is just an http request.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".link-text").click(function () {
            var $contentPanelId = jQuery(this).attr("id");
            var $test = ("Images/Pictures/materials/" + $contentPanelId + "/");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'php_functions.php',
                data: {
                    name: $test
                },
                success: function (path) {
                    $('#somthing').append(path);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```